# Integrate node.js project in lein build

Tags: node.js, leiningen

I have a seperate javascript frontend project that comes with its own package.json. I want to integrate this project into my leiningen build in such a way that requires no additional setup (such as installing node and npm). Usually build tools such as Maven or gradle provide plugins that download a certain node version + npm, install all dependencies and then run a script to build the javascript project. Is there such a plugin for leiningen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody bothered to answer, I ended up using mvn to glue the node.js and leiningen project together. My leiningen project builds using `immutant war` and my node.js project using `npm run build`. It uses the `maven-frontend-plugin` to install node and npm and execute the node build. It uses the `exec-maven-plugin` to execute leiningen in a seperate VM. Here is the `pom.xml` excluding project information.

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
     <id>clojars</id>
     <name>Clojars</name>
     <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
   </repository>
 </repositories>

 <dependencies>
  <!-- Taken from http://www.elangocheran.com/blog/2015/12/compiling-a-leiningen-project-from-maven/ -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
   <artifactId>clojure</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>leiningen</groupId>
   <artifactId>leiningen</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.1</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>clojars</id>
   <name>Clojars</name>
   <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
  </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>

 <build>
  <plugins>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>install node and npm</id>
      <goals>
       <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <configuration>
       <nodeVersion>v8.2.1</nodeVersion>
       <npmVersion>5.3.0</npmVersion>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
     <execution>
      <id>npm install</id>
      <goals>
       <goal>npm</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <configuration>
       <arguments>install</arguments>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
     <execution>
      <id>npm build</id>
      <goals>
       <goal>npm</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <configuration>
       <arguments>run build</arguments>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>lein war</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <executable>java</executable>
       <arguments>
        <argument>-classpath</argument>
        <classpath />
        <argument>clojure.main</argument>
        <argument>-m</argument>
        <argument>leiningen.core.main</argument>
        <argument>immutant</argument>
        <argument>war</argument>
       </arguments>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>


  </plugins>
 </build>
```